# Probabilistic algorithm

Tags: algorithm, probability

We are given a binary array that has either **n zeros** or **floor(n/2) zeros** and **ceiling(n/2) ones**.

We want to decide whether the array includes ones.

Q. Suggest a random algorithm that has time complexity O(1) and gives the correct answer with a probability of at least 3/4. The algorithm can give a wrong answer but not for more than 1/4 possible inputs.

I would like to get some direction on how to solve this question.

Comment: What proportion of input arrays contain 1’s? Are half the arrays all zeros? A third? 90%?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check *random* item in the array:

1. If `item == 0` return first possibility (**n zeroes**)
2. If `item == 1` return second possibility (**n/2 zeroes and n/2 ones**)

Let's have a look what's going on: the only possibility to give incorrect answer is when we have *second possibility*,
but we get `item == 0` and answer is *first possibility*. The conditional (second possibility) probability is

```
p = 1/2
```

If we check *two* random items

```
p = 1/4 (two items are zeroes)
```

If we check *three* random items

```
p = 1/8 (three items are zeroes)
```

Now, let's compute bayesian probability of incorrect answer, let

```
P0 - probability of the 1st (all zeroes) outcome
P1 - probability of the 2nd (half zeroes, half ones) outcome

Perror = P1 * p / (P0 + P1) <= 1/4
```

Or

```
P1 * p / (P0 + P1) <= 1/4

p <= (P0 + P1) / 4 / P1

p <= P0 / (4 * P1) + 1/4
```

From the *worst case*, `P0 = 0` (`P1 = 1`) we get condition for `p`:

```
p <= 1/4
```

So far so good, we should check *two random* array's items and then

- If *both* items are `0`, we answer "All zeroes case"
- If *any* item is `1`, we answer "Half zeroes, half ones case"